# How to set custom directive value to true or false in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have an custom directive which shows the currency. This custom directive is used in component.html file. How can I set this custom directive value to true or false based on some condition in component.html.

*component.html*

```
 <input
 type="text"
  currency
 />
```

I have tried appliying

```
 [currency] = "condition?true:false"
```

also

```
[attr.currency] = "condition?true:false"
```

Comment: Please post your directive `.ts`

Comment: @Chaka15 It only returns Rs or $ etc

Comment: You always can to have two inputs (one with the directive and another one without it and use `*ngIf` (Yes I know is not an real answer, but it's the only I can get)